# SQL query to show changes to "total" column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains stock transactions:

```
+------+----------------------+------------------+
| Item | Running Stock Total  | Transaction Time |
+------+----------------------+------------------+
| foo  | 4                    | 2012-05-12 11:07 |
| bar  | 3                    | 2012-05-12 10:42 |
| bar  | 3                    | 2012-05-12 9:42  |
| bar  | 2                    | 2012-05-11 15:42 |
| foo  | 3                    | 2012-05-11 10:02 |
| bar  | 3                    | 2012-05-10 13:44 |
...etc...
+------+----------------------+------------------+
```

i.e. Any time something happens to stock, a row is created in this table- this may mean the stock level goes up (new stock ordered), down(stock sold) or remains unchanged (stock relocated).

I need to create an sql query that returns only the rows where the stock level has actually changed for a particular part, and it needs to show the changes in a "stock up" and "stock down" column.

i.e. 1 `Item='bar'`

```
+------+-----------+------------+----------------------+------------------+
| Item | Stock Up  | Stock Down | Running Stock Total  | Transaction Time |
+------+-----------+------------+----------------------+------------------+
| bar  |      1    |     0      |  3                   | 2012-05-12 9:42  |
| bar  |      0    |     1      |  2                   | 2012-05-11 15:42 |
| bar  |      1    |     0      |  3                   | 2012-05-10 13:44 |
+------+-----------+------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

e.g.2 `Item='foo'`

```
+------+-----------+------------+----------------------+------------------+
| Item | Stock Up  | Stock Down | Running Stock Total  | Transaction Time |
+------+-----------+------------+----------------------+------------------+
| foo  |      1    |     0      |  4                   | 2012-05-12 11:07 |
| foo  |      2    |     0      |  3                   | 2012-05-11 10:02 |
+------+-----------+------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

So something like...

```
SELECT 
  Item, {xyz} as 'Stock Up', {abc} as 'Stock Down',  `Running Stock Total`, `Transaction Time`
FROM
  `StockTransactions`
WHERE
  `Item`='foo'
HAVING 
  ('Stock Up'>0 or 'Stock Down'>0)
```

Can this be done?

Comment: How do you differentiate when the stock went up and when the stock went down?

Comment: By using the "Running Stock Total"

Comment: Your syntax looks like SQL Server, yet your question is tagged MySQL.  Which are you using?

Comment: Ok. In your example 2, The running stock total decreased but there is not entry in the Stock Down column.

Comment: @ eggyal It's MySQL. What makes it look like SQL server?

Comment: @Juniad No it didn't. The stock went up from 3 to 4. It's chronological.

Comment: @Urbycoz: `[]` are not valid identifier quotes in MySQL...

Comment: @eggyal Those aren't part of the sql. They are just to show the sql that needs to be written. I'll change them to {}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT   `Item`,
         `Stock Up`,
         `Stock Down`,
         `Running Stock Total`,
         `Transaction Time`

FROM (
  SELECT   `Item`,
           GREATEST(`Running Stock Total` - @`last_total`, 0) AS `Stock Up`,
           GREATEST(@`last_total` - `Running Stock Total`, 0) AS `Stock Down`,
           `Running Stock Total`,
           `Transaction Time`,
           @`last_total` := `Running Stock Total`
  FROM     `StockTransactions` JOIN (SELECT @`last_total` := 0) AS lt
  WHERE    `Item` = 'bar'
  ORDER BY `Transaction Time` ASC
) AS t

ORDER BY `Transaction Time` DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22939/1).  The outer query can obviously be omitted if you're happy for the results to be ordered in ascending order of transaction time and with the extra `last_total` column.

Comment: The outer query cannot be omitted, because it is in the outer query that the rows can (and must) be filtered on the `'Stock Up'>0 or 'Stock Down'>0` condition (which is required by the question and which you are not doing). Other than that, I think your solution should work.

Comment: @eggyal This is an excellent and elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My solution works based on the assumption, that `Transaction Time` is unique per `Item`.

I am simulating `row_number()` analytical function via the helper view that I create:

```sql
CREATE VIEW running_stock AS
SELECT s.item,s.running_total,s.transaction_dt,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM stock WHERE item=s.item
      AND transaction_dt <= s.transaction_dt) AS row_number
  FROM stock s
 ORDER BY 1, 4;
```

After view is in place, you can obtain the desired results with the following query:

```sql
SELECT c.item AS "Item",
  greatest(c.running_total - p.running_total, 0) AS "Stock Up",
  greatest(p.running_total - c.running_total, 0) AS "Stock Down",
  c.running_total AS "Running Total",
  c.transaction_dt AS "Transaction Time"
FROM running_stock c
LEFT JOIN running_stock p ON c.item = p.item
      AND p.row_number + 1 = c.row_number
WHERE c.row_number > 1
ORDER BY 1, 5;
```

You can play with this query on the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32afa/2).

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be:

1. Make a cursor to select each row at a time
2. Check if the value changed and if so, insert the info in a #temp table
3. Select all data from the #temp table

Instead of a cursor you may use a while cycle if you can identify sequencially all rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like setting a variable that contains the old stock price. First sort the table by item so that you can deal with all of the data for each stock by itself.

Then you can say something like 
int counter = 0;
            decimal startingPrice = 0;
            decimal cost = 0;

```
        var list = new List<Decimal>();
        Decimal[] positivePercentagesToTest = new Decimal[] { 1.02m, 1.03m, 1.04m, 1.10m, 100 };
        Decimal[] negativePercentagesToTest = new Decimal[] { 0.99m, 0.985m, 0.98m, 0.95m, 0.9m };

        for (int i = 0; i <= positivePercentagesToTest.Count() -1 ;i++ )
        {
            foreach (var s in stocks)
            {
                //if(s.Ticker == "BAC")
                {
                    if (counter == 0)
                    {
                        startingPrice = s.Open;
                    }
                    counter++;

                    var openPrice = s.Open;

                    if (openPrice > (startingPrice * positivePercentagesToTest[i]) || openPrice < (startingPrice * negativePercentagesToTest[i]))
                    {
                        //sell
                        //same as percentage gain
                        var percentage = openPrice/startingPrice - 1;

                        list.Add(Math.Round(percentage, 2));
                        counter = 0;
                    }

                }

            }

            var amount = list.Sum();
            var profitToAdd = new Profits();
            profitToAdd.Amount = amount;
```

This is C# code. If you need it in sql, let me know. This is just the logic I would use.

Comment: I'm afraid I do need it in sql.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your SQL flavour, but in Oracle there are `LAG()` and `LEAD()` analytic functions that allow you to access column values from previous or next row in the result set. You could use `LAG()` to see the difference between previous and current result and decide whether is was up or down. Is there anything similar in your SQL?

Comment: I'm using MySQL. Don't think it has anything similar.